# Is it possible to use the Markov Blanket to determine whether two nodes are conditionally independent?

Tags: machine-learning, directed-acyclic-graphs, bayesian-networks, markov

A target node is independent of all other nodes in a Bayesian network given its Markov Blanket.
I am confused how this can be applied. Can I for example target any node in the graph
to determine its independence from another node?

Consider this example:

[image: Example]
How would I determine whether **J** is independent of **K** given **W**?

Answer (score 1):

For this query that you have chosen, **J** is not independent of **K** given **W**, simply because **K** is part of **J's** Markov blanket. Also, **J** cannot be independent of **K** because **K** is **J's** Parent.

In general, we can determine if 2 nodes are conditionally independent of each other (given some other nodes) based on the following scenarios:

1) Indirect "Causal" Effect

- **K** is independent of **W** given **J**

2) Indirect Evidential Effect

- **W** is independent of **K** given **J**

3) Common "Cause"

- **G** is independent of **W** given **C**

4) Common Effect / Collider

- **B** is **NOT** independent of **T** given **X** (i.e. X acts as a collider, and if we know information about X, **B** and **T** can be
  dependent) If **X** is **NOT OBSERVED**, then **B** and **T** are
  marginally independent.

It is not entirely necessary to use Markov Blankets to determine if 2 nodes are independent of each other.

But to give you a better understanding of how Markov blanket can be applied to determine independence, lets consider the node **C**

Given **C's** Markov Blanket, **L, G, W, J**, which are **C's** Parents, Children, and Children's Parents, **C** is then independent of every other node in the Bayesian Network.

Therefore, we can say that:
**C** is independent of **B, X, T, K**, given **L, G, W, J**